# Porquê que createEvent não funciona no firefox

Tags: jquery, html

Tenho uma div que dentro dessa div contém um `select option` como `hidden` e tenho um script em jquery que ao clicar no botão mostra a listar com as `option` está a funcionar bem em todos os navegadores só no firefox e que não funciona ao clicar não acontece nada.

**Script**

```
$('#botao_categoria').on("click", function () {
  var e = document.createEvent("MouseEvents")
  e.initMouseEvent('mousedown');
  $('#categoria')[0].dispatchEvent(e);
});
```

**HTML**

```
 <div id="categoria_label" class="input_home_pequisa"><span>Escolha uma  categoria</span>
<img id="botao_categoria" style="float:right; margin-top:4px;  cursor:pointer;" src="img/select_home.png">
 </div>
 <div style="visibility: hidden; margin-left:15px;">
<select name="categoria" id="categoria">
  <option value="Escolha uma categoria">Escolha uma categoria</option>
  <option value="restauracao">Restauração</option>
  <option value="hotelaria">Hotélaria</option>
  <option value="comercios">Comércios</option>
  <option value="servicos">Serviços</option>
  <option value="lazer">Lazer</option>
  <option value="bares">Bares</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Talvez porque [esse método esteja sendo descontinuado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent) em favor dos construtores de eventos como [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso não é possível no Firefox. [Nem usando a nova API.](https://jsfiddle.net/x4shvpLu/)

Tens de fazer um drop-down manual, com HTML e CSS que simule o que precisas;  aumentar o tamanho dando a ilusão de que está aberto (https://jsfiddle.net/gL21pssm/); ou usar um plugin com essa funcionalidade (por exemplo o https://code.google.com/p/expandselect/)

Comment: acabei usando o plugin do google funcionou perfeitamente. obrigado